Gemini Python API Deadline Exceeded
I have been trying to use Google's Gemini API using python, and I am running into continuous  504 Deadline Exceeded. This is also not a one of thing as well, I have tried 20+ times using python SDK and it failed everytime, while curl returned in 5-6 seconds everytime.
I initially thought this was a network problem, but a simple curl calls works well.
I have a very basic starter script:
genai.configure(api_key=key)
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life")
print(response.text)

The response I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life.")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/generativeai/generative_models.py", line 232, in generate_content
    response = self._client.generate_content(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/generative_service/client.py", line 566, in generate_content
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
    _retry_error_helper(
  File ..env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
    raise final_exc from source_exc
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 144, in retry_target
    result = target()
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded


The curl call though works as expected:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"contents":[{"parts":[{"text":"What is the meaning of life"}]}]}' \
    -X POST 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?key={key}'

{
  "candidates": [
    {
      "content": {
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "In the life....



Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?

I tested your code and it works fine the python code.  504 Deadline Exceeded is a GRCP error meaning that the stream timed out.  I wonder if your internet connection is just slow.  try something simpler like "What is the meaning of life in two sentences"

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I dont think its the connection being slow, I have a 200mbps dedicated connection. Also, the same prompt works with curl everytime. I would've understood if it worked sometimes, then I could have understood it maybe due to the network. right now it fails 100% times from python but 0% with curl. I will try with requests module as well.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I tried it with requests module as well. The results are pasted here: https://pastebin.com/eiXLFHf1 . It seems like somehow there's some network issue with the actual urls the python sdk is trying to reach, because the api calls only give 504s with the sdk. requests work as well. Any idea if i can figure out the urls being hit within the sdk so as to figiure out the issue?

For vendor problems, post on their website or use their support channels. Google provides the Issue Tracker to handle bug reports and service interface issues. Repost your problem here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers Suggestion: Until May 2, I recommend using your working REST API code. A lot of changes are happening, some will be announced next week. Which country are you making requests from? Which SDK and version are you using? Do you have antivirus installed? Have you tried your code on a different machine? Edit your post with details and not with comments.

Thanks John, I will follow your advice and post on the issue-tracker.

Update your question with the details I requested as well. You will need to provide those details on the Issue Tracker.

This worked for me:
response = model.generate_content(
    contents=messages, 
    request_options={"timeout": 1000}
)


This solved it in my case, although the servers were specially slow and I had to increase the timeout value.

I had this exact same issue while using Gemini embedding model via python SDK inside for loop, Although I haven't tried CURL call.
What I'm aware is that there is a 60 request/min rate limit on Gemini service & other GCP services as well. 504 Deadline Exceeded. To overcome this, you can add a try/except block and put a sleep of 120 sec using python time module.
Try the below code:
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
try:
    response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life")
    
except Exception as e
    time.sleep(120)
    response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life")
    

If the above solution does not work then I think someone might have access to your API key and they using it. So simply refresh your key.

Hi, I don't think this is the issue, because i created the api key literally minutes before trying out gemini. But still just to cover all bases, I re-created the api key and tried it with the new key with same result. The results are pasted here: https://pastebin.com/eiXLFHf1 . The thing is, rate limitng would make sense if i was making many new requests in bulk, but this is the first time I'm tring this and I have created 2 new keys for the same, and only sdk is causing the issue. both curl and python requests are giving me response everytime. I think this could be a network issue,

I'm assuming you are using Generative Language client when you created the api. is it ?

Yes, I'm using google.generativeai sdk in python 3.12.
